# Proof verification: $Hom_A(P,M) \cong Hom_A(P,A)\otimes_A M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian ring, let $P$ be a free $A$-module, and let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module.

I want to show that $Hom_A(P,M) \cong Hom_A(P,A) \otimes_A M$.

Here is my proof:

First, this obviously holds if $M$ is a finitely generated free $A$-module.

Since $A$ is noetherian, $M$ is finitely presented, so we have an exact sequence

$A^m \to A^n \to M \to 0$.

Now, since $P$ is projective, the functor $Hom_A(P,-)$ is exact.

Since $A$ is noetherian, the $A$-module $Hom_A(P,A)$, which is a (possibly infinite) direct product of copies of $A$, is a flat $A$-module. Hence, the functor $Hom_A(P,A)\otimes_A -$ is also exact.

Now, we may use the standard trick: we have two exact sequences

$Hom_A(P,A^m) \to Hom_A(P,A^n) \to Hom_A(P,M) \to 0$

$Hom_A(P,A)\otimes_A A^m \to Hom_A(P,A)\otimes_A A^n \to Hom_A(P,A)\otimes_A M \to 0$

with obvious maps between them, and the two leftmost maps are isomorphisms, so the right map is also an isomorphism.

Is this proof correct?

Thanks!

Comment: It's good, apart from a minor point: $\mathrm{Hom}_A(P,A)$ is a summand of a direct product of copies of $A$.

Comment: why a summand? $P$ is a direct sum of copies of $A$, so $Hom_A(P,A)$ is a direct product of copies of $A$, no?

Comment: Oh, sorry! $P$ is free, not just projective. But, as you see, the proof carries over also in the case $P$ is projective.

Comment: What I find interesting here is that usually these proofs does not need $A$ to be noetherian, by replacing f.g with finitely presented. But in this case we really need $A$ to be noetherian (or at least coherent).

Comment: I'd possibly add the definition of the homomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_A(P,A)\otimes M\to\mathrm{Hom}_A(P,M)$, just for completeness. And, yes, you need the product of flat modules to be flat. Or that $P$ is finitely generated projective.